# How can I run every program as administrator in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

Is there a way to simply run **every** program in Windows 7 as an administrator?

I wanted to change something in the hosts file but Windows didn't let me until I started Notepad with administrator rights. I then tried to run FileZilla server on xampp but I was unable to until I started xampp in admin mode.

I'm tired of running into strange issues related to this.

Comment: Turn UAC off, or log on as admin?

Answer (score 1):

This is a better question for http://superuser.com .  That said, you can use the "User Accounts" control panel, "Change User Account Control Settings", and change the slider to "Never Notify".  Not recommended, but as long as your account is already in the "Administrators" group, this should give you what you're looking for.